Burpsuite Java versions conflict
I have a Burp Suite version that needs Java 21 to run. But I have other apps that needs Java 8 so I have both versions on my PC. The problem is that if I install a new update of Java 8 then burpsuite can't detect Java 21 and won't launch unless I do reinstall Java 21 again.
How can I solve this problem?
The only solution I am doing is to reinstall Java 21 again so that the program works and detects 21.

You can easily change which JDK is the current default in SDKMAN!. See doc.

While the JAVA_HOME advice is generally correct, it won't work when you launch Burb Suite from the command prompt.  According to the documentation, you the command-line launch incantation for Burp Suite is:
 java -Xmx4g -jar  /path/to/burp.jar

That will not respect JAVA_HOME.  But it is easy to adapt this to your scenario.  All you need to do is to use the absolute path to your Java 21 installation.
First find where Java 21 is installed, and confirm it by running this.
 /path/to/your/java21/bin/java -version

to make sure that you have Java 21 installed1, then launch Burp Suite like this:
 /path/to/your/java21/bin/java -Xmx4g -jar  /path/to/burp.jar

You could easily write a wrapper script or batch file to do that.

1 - You can have multiple versions of Java installed at the same time.  What you get when you run java (on Windows) will depend on the PATH environment variable.  So another strategy would be to change that variable.

You can install multiple versions of Java in parallel. When running any program that relies of Java, it should look for it under the JAVA_HOME environment variable, so you could set it to the one that's required by the program you're trying to run before attempting to run it.
